# Komodo Project Template Macros

Tags: ruby-on-rails, komodo

What is the use of **`oncreate`** macro in komodo project? 
How it could be used in Ruby on rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Komodo project templates can have a special macro called oncreate which run when a new project is created from the template. The oncreate macro in this Ruby on Rails template runs the command 'rails . --skip' in the current working directory to create the project.

Got this from: http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/5.0/tutorial/railstut.html